# Displaying app icon in notification bar

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on this app. what i want to do is display the icon of my activity in notification bar on a button click. i want it to stay there permanently until some other event is done. currently i dound this code but its giving a lot of errors, kindly tell me an easy way to do this:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(icon.isChecked()) {
                    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

                    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
                    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Track Your Life", System.currentTimeMillis());

                    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                            new Intent(), 0);

                    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.local_service_label), text, contentIntent);

                    // Send the notification.
                    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: add print screen what you want to achieve

Comment: i simply want my app's icon to stay in the notification bar. Just like  Whatsapp or skype icon when youre online.

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "a lot of errors" means. Also, you may wish to use `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead of trying to create a `Notification` yourself directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code for create Notification with icon

```
Intent intentSetDefault = new Intent(mContext, ConversationListActivity.class);
        PendingIntent piSetDeafult = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intentSetDefault,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // create pending intent for action discard
        Intent intentdiscard = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReceiver.class).setType(CODE_DISCARD);
        PendingIntent piDiscard = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intentdiscard,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                            .setTicker(title)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_incoming_msg)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setLargeIcon(mAppBitmap)
                            .setContentInfo(Integer.toString(smsCount))
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setAutoCancel(false);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(piSetDeafult);

            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            mNotifyMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_SET_DEFAULT, notification);
```

Comment: Can't find mContext, piSetDefault, mNotifyMgr

Comment: add that members context is simple context and notifyMgr is notificaiton manager